# Take one condition & show result from two different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 3 data tables (quick version):

```
Payments:
id | datepaid | amountpaid
---------------------------
112|03/5/2017 |9000
115|03/21/2017| 800

Individuals:
id|name|lastDatePaid
--------------------
112|bob|03/2/2017
114|kary|2/3/2016

Business:
id|name|lastDatePaid
--------------------
115| Bakery Love | 05/20/2017
```

My question is: how would I get the result of both business name and individual name when the condition is the for each payment that was made on or after March 2, 2017?

I was able to get show result in one condition, but I don't seem to understand to get both individual and business to show up?

**Want result:**

```
112|bob
115|Bakery Love
```

This is my version that one result show for example Individual:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.id, i1.name
FROM Payments p1, Individuals i1
WHERE p1.datePaid >= DATE '2017-03-01' AND p1.id = i1.id;
```

Which this code result only to:

```
112|bob
```

Also I've read a book that this code is also equivalent, but I don't think so?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.id, i1.name
FROM Individuals i1, Payments p1
WHERE i1.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT p1.id
    FROM Payments p1 
    WHERE p1.datePaid >= DATE '2017-03-01');
```

When I rewrote it to try to get the same result, I ended up getting unwanted data for some reason. Apparently, it checks the dates (lastDatePaid) in the Individual and businesses table and print without having that AND condition that it should be the id from the payments.(this is the full version of the data).

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: this is just a simple database. I'm using psql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Er, I figure it out. 
I didn't need to use the JOIN statement rather this

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.ID, N.name
FROM Payments p1, (SELECT i1.name, i1.ID
      FROM Individuals i1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT b1.name, b1.ID
      FROM Businesses b1) AS N 
WHERE p1.datePaid >= DATE '2017-03-01' AND p1.ID = N.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is to put the 'name' tables on top of each other.

```
Select * from individuals
Union all
Select * from business
```

Then you make that a sub query and join it to the payment table...

```
Select p.id, n.name
From
Payments p
Join
```

(
    Select * from individuals
    Union all
    Select * from business) as n
    On n.id = p.id

It looks like you have figured how to get the date filter to work, so I won't bother adding that.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, totally make sense. Thank you so much!